# Flash - Compile .as3proj file

Tags: flash

I just downloaded a sample Flash project.

This sample project doesn't come with a .fla file. Instead it comes with a .as3proj file.

How do I compile that? Do I need Flex Builder instead?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 2):

I don't have experience with Flex Builder, but there is a free alternative, [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewforum.php?f=11), which I have used extensively. I believe that is what the `as3proj` was created in. Once installed, FlashDevelop will associate itself with that project file.

However, if you already have a development environment set up, it should be fairly easy to copy the files into a new project since Flash/Flex has a strict package hierarchy.